# ASP.net MVC with AS3 — user sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3, session

I have searched high and low for answers on this topic but have not found anything to direct me in the right direction.

I want to add the ability to have my flash game record the users progress then save to a database. That part is pretty easy, but how can I make it so the user can login and continue their game.

I also wanting to know if it'll be better for the game progress to be saved with SharedObjects or with an SQL database.

I would like it that the game could be played on any website and their data can still be accessed and played if that is advised. I am new to user sessions with AS3 and need pointers.

I appreciate any help. Let me know if I need to explain better.

Comment: a few pointers:
0x3A28213A
0x6339392C
0x7363682E

Comment: Ha ha, very funny. I don't appreciate your sarcasm.

Comment: Your question is quite weird with the tags,, where is asp.net-mvc come in play?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that I am considering using ASP.net MVC as my server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deploy a WCF service on your ASP.NET server and use the service to retrieve and set data to your database, including verifying if the login was correct and if so send back the gamesession data.

You can send a byte array with WCF as well strings, int and any other datatype including classes as long as they are propperly setup.

To have flash able to connect to a website from anywhere the site needs a cross domain policy file other wise flash (or silverlight for that matter) will not be able to connect to the service.

[Silverlight cross domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[Flash cross domain](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

[(blah.winsmarts.com)WCF Hello World Tutorial (one of the better ones)](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_the_WCF_Hello_World_App.aspx)

[(blah.winsmarts.com)Host on IIS7 and Win2k8](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx)

[Wcf tutorial (not the best)](http://www.wcftutorial.net/)

[Setup server for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx)

Comment: Wow these are great articles. Thanks